# javascript-- changing the innerHTML of an image

Tags: javascript, image, mouseover, innerhtml

So I JUST asked a question and I've already hit another roadblock.  Thanks so much to the stackoverflow community for helping me out so much recently :)

Every time I see people changing the innerHTML of some tag, they use document.getElementByID(id).innerHTML.  My images do NOT have ids, nor do I want to give each and every one of them an id.

Here is my code:

```
function clickImages()
{
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
     var delegate = function() { hover(this); };

  images[i].onmouseover = delegate;
}
}

function hover(img)
{
img.innerHTML = "Text!";
}
```

The innerHTML doesn't seem like it's working; when I mouse over the image nothing changes.

Thanks in advance!  Let me know if I can clarify!

Comment: Are you trying to change the alt text or the img title attribute? What exactly are you trying to do to the image with this `hover` function?

Comment: Image elements don't have any content, so they don't have any innerHTML.

Comment: Oh, I'm trying to display text rather than the image.  I guess that makes sense.  Oops :)

Comment: You may change the front glass of the car, but you can't change the front glass of the horse. Bec there is no front glass for the horse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is itself a replaced element, so there is no `innerHTML` to replace.

Based on your comment, if you want to add HTML adjacent to the image, you could do this:

```
img.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', 'HTML code');
```

You could also change 'afterend' to 'beforebegin' if you wanted to add the HTML before the image.

Writing on the image itself would be much more complicated and would require positioning another element above it with a transparent background, or using the image itself as the background of another element, or a variety of other similar techniques.

Comment: Is there a way for me to change the image to say text, or write text over the image?

Comment: You could do `img.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode('text'), img);`

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I understand this much better now!  :)

Comment: @RobG might have correctly guessed at what you actually want to do. Try his suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way to get the image back?  Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: No, that's the problem if you replace the image element. If you want to get the image "back" then set its `style.display` property to "none" rather than replacing it. You will be able to change this property back to an empty string again in order to get the image back.

Comment: If you keep a reference to the element, it can remain available but not visible (or even part of the DOM if you wish). Or you can toggle its visibility or display properties to be the opposite of an adjacent text element, as Joseph suggests, so that only one or the other is shown.

Answer (score 0):

> [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)
>
> innerHTML sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's
>   descendants

`innerHTML` means the HTML that comes between the start and end HTML tags. Images don't have `innerHTML`

I am not sure what you want to achieve.

If you want to have a text displayed `onmouseover`, you can use the `title` attribute to do that.. for example:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" title="Hello" />
```

If you are trying to replace the image with text on `onmouseover` ... then as an example (only to show the possibilities), the following code will hide the image & display a text `onmouseover` and make the image visible & remove the text `onmouseout` (although not very satisfactorily IMHO, more work has to be done on the code to improve it)

Please note: There shouldn't be any gap between the image tag and the span for this particular code to work. Also, a negative `margin-left` added to the span element can make it appear over the location of the image.

```
<img onmouseover="toText(this)" onmouseout="toImage(this)" src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley" /><span style="visibility: hidden; margin-left: -30px;">Show Text</span>

function toText(img) {

 img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 img.nextSibling.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

function toImage(img) {

  img.style.visibility = 'visible';
  img.nextSibling.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Good luck
:)